# ClassNotFoundException MySql JDBC connector error only if entire project is run

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

The following code runs without any errors and output the MySQL version:

```
public class ConnectionMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection();
    mySqlConnection.printVersion();
  }
}
```

But when I try to run the `printVersion()` function anywhere in the client or server code (same project), I get the well-known `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. What might be causing this issue? Is my `mysql-connector.jar` not building properly when I run the project? The file is already is the IntelliJ dependencies.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MySqlConnection {

  private final static Logger.Log LOG = Logger.newLog(MySqlConnection.class);

  private static final String DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/message_db?useSSL=false";
  private static final String USERNAME = "root";
  private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

  private Properties properties;
  private Statement statement;
  private ResultSet rs;

  private Properties getProperties() {
    if (properties == null) {
      properties = new Properties();
      properties.setProperty("user", USERNAME);
      properties.setProperty("password", PASSWORD);
    }
    return properties;
  }

  private Connection connect() {
    Connection connection;
    try {

      Class.forName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, getProperties());
      if (connection != null) {
        return connection;
      }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

      System.out.println("ERROR: Exception in MySqlConnection.connect. Check log for details.");
      LOG.error(e, "Exception in MySqlConnection.connect");

    }
    return null;
  }

  private void close() {
    try {
      if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
        rs = null;
      }

      if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
        statement = null;
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

      System.out.println("ERROR: Exception in MySqlConnection.close. Check log for details.");
      LOG.error(e, "Exception in MySqlConnection.close");

    }
  }

  public void printVersion() {
    Connection connection = connect();

    try {

      statement = connection.createStatement();
      rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

      if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        LOG.info(rs.getString(1));
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

      close();
      if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the jar is available during deployment

Comment: explain how exactly you run the app

Comment: @Yohannes how do you check that in IntelliJ? I have the jar in the dependencies and then I build the project.

Comment: @Yohannes @OleksandrShpota I run a bash file to run `ServerMain.java` by passing the port and other config as arguments. If I add `Class.forName(DATABASE_DRIVER);` in the main function of ServerMain.java, I see the same error. However, if I just right-click and run `ServerMain.java` alone, I don't see the error.

Comment: @YashMittal  If you are using a bash script to run your application, there is a possibility that you are not using the build path definition in your IDE(InteliJ) , there might be a class path definition in your script that missed the jar. Could you verify what is in your bash script??

Comment: @Yohannes Thank you! I was certainly missing `-cp` in the `java` command. I didn't know we had to explicitly define the classpath, but it all makes sense now.